# MySQL Dynamic Condition by column's value?

Tags: php, mysql

Given a situation that I am not sure if the stored value is a serialized array or a simple integer, is there a way to check before applying the correct condition? I'll give an example:

```
user_id | prefs
----------------
1       | 1
2       | {serialized_php_array}
```

Now I want to check where there is no specific value in `prefs` so I need to so something like:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE prefs NOT LIKE ":value;" OR prefs != "value"`

The first condition rules out serialized array values, and the second condition rules out the simple integer.

The problem is that they cannot co-exist in the same condition and I need to ask MySQL if the value is serialized and only then do the `"NOT LIKE :value;"` condition.  Is there a way to achieve that?

P.S - English is not my mother tongue so I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Your current method of storing serialized data in the `prefs` column is not a good one, but that being said your current query should actually work.  Can you show us sample data and your expected output?

Comment: You should use `AND`, not `OR`.

Comment: have your tried using IN Clause?

Comment: one solution for that could be `CASE WHEN`

Comment: @Barmar the database design is not up to me, but I still need to make my code work based on that db design ;/

Comment: @Broshi I never said anything about the database design. I just told you to change `OR` to `AND` and then it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is wrong, you should be using `AND`, not `OR`.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE prefs NOT LIKE ":value;" AND prefs != "value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are scenario(s) your prefs is a serialized data using wild card would solve it

```
prefs NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", ":value;", "%")
```

Your would should look like this

```
SELECT * FROM table where prefs NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", ":value;", "%") AND prefs != "value"
```